# How to compare the components of two lists python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I want to compare two lists, row by row. If 2 rows are equal, add just one of the 2 rows to a new dataframe. But if not, add both rows to the new dataframe.

These are my both lists:

```
original = data_Unos['text']

13      Speaking to Africa Review   he also pointed ou...
17      Through Gawad Kalinga   Meloto has proven to b...
21      May you attain Nibbana Sena   thank you so muc...
22      Dodgeballs were flying fast and hard at Mornin...
26      Most are from desperately poor Horn of Africa ...
                              ...                        
3155    The statement signed by Ikonomwan Francis   le...
3159      Most of them   the homeless   have the abili...
3162      In Metro Manila   7 464 families of disabled...
3163      We are working with an aim to build a countr...
3172    Our hearts go out to the hundreds of thousands...
Name: text, Length: 794, dtype: object
```

And:

```
backTranslated = backTranslated['text']
backTranslated

0      Talking to Africa Review also noted that most ...
1      Through Gawad Kalinga Meloto has proven to be ...
2      May you reach Nibbana Sena thank you so much f...
3      Dodgeballs were flying fast and hard at Mornin...
4      Most of them are from poor countries in the Ho...
                             ...                        
789    The declaration signed by Ikonomwan Francis le...
790    Most of them homeless have the ability to work...
791    In Metro Manila 7 464 families of disabled cyc...
792    We are working with the objective of building ...
793    Our hearts are directed to the hundreds of tho...
Name: text, Length: 794, dtype: object
```

And this is what I'm trying to do:

```
final = pd.DataFrame()

for i in original:
  for j in backTranslated:
    if(set(i)!=set(j)):
      final = final.append(i,ignore_index=True) 
      final = final.append(j,ignore_index=True) 
    else:
      final = final.append(i,ignore_index=True)
```

But the following error appears in this line:

```
final = final.append(j,ignore_index=True)

   TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

How can I do that?

Comment: where did you define `final` and what is it and in which line of your code you get this error ?

Comment: I have edited my question to answer yours

Comment: what's the purpose of `set(i) != set(j)`?  Right now it compares the unicode codepoint sets of the two strings. If this is intentional, you should precompute this instead of computing it once for each combination. Your code doesn't have to have quadratic runtime (plus)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to append both of them and remove duplicates:

```
final = data_Unos.append(backTranslated)
final.drop_duplicates(subset=['text'], inplace=True)
```

Iterating in Pandas should be last resource

Comment: If the asker truly wants to use their `set(text)` criterium it can be done with something like `df.assign(key=df["text"].apply(frozenset)).drop_duplicates(subset=["key"]).drop(columns="key")`   i.e. deduplicate by that set

Comment: @creanion or just `new_df = pd.DataFrame({'text': set().union(original, backTranslated)})`... so the new frame is only from the reduced subset rather than creating a frame and then deduplicating it...

Comment: @JonClements That's a different operation from what's going on in the question.

Comment: @creanion umm... is it? I might be reading it incorrectly... may I ask how you're reading it?

Comment: Asker is doing `for i in original` so `i` is a string element from a series, the incoming text column. So `set(i)` is the set of whatever that string iterates to i.e "the letters".   I think it's a valid operation for some textual analysis but should be called out to avoid confusion. And I'm not 100% sure it's intentional.

Comment: Jon's version is applying `set` to the list of strings, the asker is applying set to each element of the "list".

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.DataFrame.append` method is deprecated since 1.4.0, The alternative is to use `pandas.concat` method.

This is how [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) method is defined

> pandas.concat(objs, axis=0, join='outer', ignore_index=False, keys=None, levels=None, names=None, verify_integrity=False, sort=False, copy=True)

The parameter `objs`, here needs to be either a Series or Dataframe objects. So the correct way to do it in your code is

```py
final = pd.DataFrame()

for i in original:
  for j in backTranslated:
    series_i = pd.Series(i)
    if(set(i)!=set(j)):
      series_j = pd.Series(j)
      final = pd.concat((final, series_i, series_j), ignore_index=True) 
    else:
      final = pd.concat((final, series_i), ignore_index=True)
```

Furthermore you can define the column name via the `key` parameter.